# Unowned self does not cause runtime to break when self is deallocated?

Tags: swift, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting, combine

I am fairly acquainted with memory management in swift, and I know that if in the capturing closure we use [unowned self] code will break, if self becomes nil and we call some method on self. Still I have been dabbling in combine and have found curios case, self becomes nil, but code never breaks. I tried to test it some more, to explain what is happening, but could not. Here is the example:

```
class DetailsViewController: UIViewController {

var subject: PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>!
var localIntHolder: Int!
private var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    subject
        .flatMap { [unowned self] value in
            self.completionPublisher()
        }
        .map({ [unowned self] value in
            self.increaseValue(value)
        })
        .sink { [unowned self] value in
            print("\(value)")
            self.localIntHolder = value
        }
        .store(in: &subscriptions)
    
    subject.send(22)
    
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

private func increaseValue(_ value: Int) -> Int {
    return value + 1
}

deinit {
    print("deinit")
}

private func completionPublisher() -> AnyPublisher<Int, Never> {
    return Future<Int, Never> { promise in
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            promise(.success(10))
        }
    }
    .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
}
```

Here is setup from main view controller:

```
let subjectInt = PassthroughSubject<Int, Never>()

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        let controller = DetailsViewController()
        controller.subject = subjectInt
        present(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Now this is simple example, sender will send value, future will delay it for 10 seconds. While this is happening I deallocate controller in the middle of it. I imagine that code will break, but nothing happens, controller is deallocated, rest of the pipeline never executed.

Is there some combine magic that I am missing?

Comment: when `DetailsViewController` is deallocated, the `subscriptions` are also deallocated, which makes them cancelled. That's the whole point of storing `subscriptions`.

Comment: In other words, yes, you're missing the magic of AnyCancellable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing `subscriptions` in

```
.store(in: &subscriptions)
```

makes sure the subscriptions are not immediately deallocated because the controller owns them (references them strongly) through its `subscriptions` variable.

When the controller is deallocated, `subscriptions` are also `deallocated`. During deallocation subscription is also cancelled, therefore the whole chain gets cancelled (including asynchronous requests, for example). That means the subscriptions won't run any more and they cannot access that `[unowned self]`.